# What do these characters stand for?

Tags: java, lwjgl

i just imported some code from a open source Minecraft client and in the net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.java class are some problems, it's about the some characters. Eclipse shows me the error: 'Invalid character constant'. Does anyone know what they stand for? :)

```
playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_vertex_uniforms]", Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è­-Š')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_fragment_uniforms]", Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è-­‰')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_vertex_attribs]", Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è¡©')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_vertex_texture_image_units]",
            Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è-­Œ')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_texture_image_units]", Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è¡²')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_caps[gl_max_texture_image_units]", Integer.valueOf(GL11.glGetInteger('è£¿')));
    GL11.glGetError();
    playerSnooper.addStatToSnooper("gl_max_texture_size", Integer.valueOf(getGLMaximumTextureSize()));
}

public static int getGLMaximumTextureSize() {
    for (int i = 16384; i > 0; i >>= 1) {
        GL11.glTexImage2D('è�¤', 0, 6408, i, i, 0, 6408, 5121, (ByteBuffer) null);
        int j = GL11.glGetTexLevelParameteri('è�¤', 0, 4096);
        if (j != 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are not using the proper encoding in Eclipse

Windows-> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

try changing the text file encoding.

Comment: I tried all encoding versions and still he doesn't know it.